# Loop with alternating object value in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a loop in R that allows me to change the value of an object within the loop. 
Below is an easy example to point out what exactly I mean by this. Print(x) stands for a rather extensive bulk of code, in which the value of x is needed for certain computations. However, while solution #1 works on paper, it is not usable in this context (because of sub loops). Is there any way to design a loop in R that resembles solution #2? Thanks a lot in advance!

```
1> x <- 1           
2> while (x == 1)
3> {
4> print(x)
5> x <- 2
6> print(x)
7> x <- 3
8> print(x)
9> x <- 4
10> print(x)
11> if (x == 4)
12> break
13> }
```

Output
1
2
3
4

```
1> x <- 1
2> while (x == 1 || x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 4)
3> {
4> print (x)
5> x <- 2
   #jump to line 2, ignore line 5, proceed with line 6
6> x <- 3
   #jump to line 2, ignore line 6, proceed with line 7
7> x <- 4
   #jump to line 2, ignore line 7, proceed with line 8
8> if (x == 4)
9> break
10> }
```

Output
1
2
3
4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is somewhat hard to tell what exactly you want to do, but I'll give a shot, too. So you first might want to write a function that takes the value of `x` and does computations depending on the value of `x` (as far as I got it from your example, the computations/loops are not the same for all `x`).

```
x <- 1:4

fct <- function(x) {
    if (x==1){
        y <- x^2
    }
    if (x==2) {
        y <- x + 2
    }
    if (x>2 & x < 5) {
        y <- x*3 + 4
    }

    return(y)
}
```

Now loop over `x`:

```
sapply(x, fct)
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks, that might actually work, I´ll try it first thing tomorrow!

Comment: It really was that simple. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's gonna work because it's not clear exactly what you want to do, but could you try to put in a vector all the values you want to run print on? Like this:

```
my_values <- c(1,2,3,4)
for(x in my_values) {
     print(x)
}
```

EDIT:

What I am gonna may be totally useless, but are you getting your next key from RODBC as well? If that's the case, suppose that you can get your next key with a function `get_next_key` and your data with `get_data`. I also assume that `get_next_key` returns `NA` if there is no more key (i.e you had the last key before). Would that work:

```
x = 1
while(!is.na(get_next_key(x))) {
     data = get_data(x)
     print(data)  
     x = get_next_key(x)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am not sure if this will work. I am using using RODBC to access a data bank where the value I assigned to x is a primary key. So x must not change for the whole computation (here, to simplify matters print(x)). After the first iteration is done however, I need x to take on a different value and repeat the whole stuff. I hope this helps.

Comment: @count: edited, although I'm not sure I understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This first obviously works only for integer increments of x:

```
x <- 1
while (x <= 4){
    print(x)
    x <- x+1
}
```

For arbitrary values of x:

```
x1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
### index x1 and move along this;
### at each step assign the value to y1 then 
### do something with (print) it
for (i in seq_along(x1)) print(y1 <- x1[i])
```

Nothing really wrong with a `for` loop here and sometimes easier to read than `apply`